# Insert an element at a linked list by using a pointer and not position

Tags: c++, insert, doubly-linked-list

I am using a custom Doubly Linked List to implement a heuristic algorithm for my thesis. I have already implemented the basic functions of a list (insert, delete etc.) and some more that are useful for the case of the problem that I am studying.

However I am a little bit troubled with the following implementation. Lets say I have a list: A->E->B->D and I want to insert the element **C** at the the best possible position inside the list. The objective function that decides the optimal position is not relevant so I won't include it.

The current implementation is the following: I call the function findBestPos(C) which returns a pointer **ptr** that points to the left element of the best insert position. For example, if **ptr** points to E, then the best insert position will be between the elements E and B.

After that, I call the function insertAt(leftElement, insertElement) which inserts the insertElement like this:

```
if(leftElement->next != nullptr){
    leftElement->next->prev = insertElement;
}

insertElement->next = leftElement->next;
leftElement->next = insertElement;
insertElement->prev = leftElement;
```

However, I keep wondering if an implementation like this is "legal". I mean, from my little experience with C++ and other languages' containers we always use the position to define where we want to insert our new element inside a container. Surely, using position will take some more time cause of the comparisons but it seems more natural, safe and reusable.

Thank you in advance.

**Update**

After @TedLyngmo's comment, I would like to include some clarifications regarding the findBestPos functionality and to demonstrate other cases that I am using similar optimizations. What I basically have is two lists:

- Unvisited
- Walk

The Unvisited list, contains all the nodes that will be considered to get inserted into the Walk list. The Walk list is basically a route of nodes that I will visit. Each node has some constant values like a visitDuration and some variables like arrivalTime, departureTime etc. that change at runtime. Also, moving from one node to another, takes some time which in my case is constant for each pair of nodes.

Let's say that I am considering to insert node k between nodes i and j of Walk. The insertion cost function is:

```
shift(k) = travelTime(ik) + waitDuration(k) + visitDuration(k) + travelTime(kj) - travelTime(ij)
```

I calculate this cost for every possible position inside the Walk. The position that minimizes this cost is the optimal.

I have used this kind of the above optimization for other functions as well. For example, when I disconnect a node from the Unvisited list I do the following:

```
void disconnect(T* curr) {
    if (head == curr) {
        head = curr->next;
    }

    if (tail == curr) {
        tail = curr->prev;
    }

    if (curr->next != nullptr) {
        curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
    }
    if (curr->prev != nullptr) {
        curr->prev->next = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = nullptr;
    curr->prev = nullptr;
}
```

As you can see, the disconnect function takes a pointer as a parameter instead of an id or a position. The head and tail pointers are private variables of the List class and they point to the first and last node of a list respectively. So for example, if I run A.disconnect(n) but node **n** in reality is the first node of list B, then node n will cut loose from its next node of list B, but B.head pointer will continue to point at **n**. Of course, it is my responsibility to not let this happen, but still it seems a little bit "hackey" to me.

Comment: You seem to think an *ordinal* position system is somehow bettter. "position" is a relative concept. You have a "position" : to the right of the thing denoted by `leftElement`. The iterator concept, used *extensively* in modern C++, is essentially the same, and it seems to work out just fine there. And fwiw, the standard library bi-directional linked list, [`std::list<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), doesn't offer any sort of *ordinal* position system either. If you need random-access then use a random access container (of which there are several).

Comment: in this case I see no reason not to use a possible optimization, after all it is one of the advantages that can give that type of container. However, in C ++ it is rare to use home made containers, there are those defined by the standard that are already very well optimized and ready to use. [STL](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library)

Comment: When you say _" the best possible position"_, do you mean that your class supports supplying a custom comparator? Perhaps a [mre] would be good - and also explain why none of the containers included in the standard library will work.

Comment: Your code seems fine, I would not use such long variable names("element" in each variable looks superfluous for me). STL chooses to replace the given node, but in a similar way you are doing, you can check this: https://codefreakr.com/how-is-c-stl-list-implemented-internally/. I would recommend using std::list, and not implement it yourself, but to answer your question, what you are doing is "legal".

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `findBestPos` return when the best position is at the head of the list, to the left of the first element?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well, actually a list represents a Walk which always has a starting and an ending point. A possible insert position should always be somewhere between these two nodes, so I start searching for the best position after the first node.

Comment: @Heto Yes, of course, I used these names for the example. Thanks for the link.  I might switch eventually to the std::list as the other guys suggested as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about iterators. Not a "pos" or or "pointer". Iterators are the standard way to solve your problem.

Seeing the function `void disconnect(T* curr)`, it seems as if you are not implementing a DoublyLinkedList, but a bunch of Nodes that are connected via pointers.

Normally, you would need a class "List" and hide all the pointer stuff in it. Even the Node can be embedded in the "List". The outside world should not know about the Node.

I cannot refactor your code, because I do no know it. What I can do is to give you an example, how a "List" with Iterators can be implemented.

Maybe this will give you an idea.

Just read the code and maybe take over one or the other concept.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This would be in a header file -----------------------------------------------------------------

// Type trait helper to identify iterators --------------------------------------------------------
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterator { static constexpr bool value = false; };
template<typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>::value>::type> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

// The List class ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
class List {
    // Sub class for a Node -----------
    struct Node {
        T data{};
        Node* next{};
        Node* previous{};
        Node() {}
        Node(Node* const n, Node* const p) : next(n), previous(p) {}
        Node(Node* const n, Node* const p, const T& d) : next(n), previous(p), data(d) {}
    };

    // Private list data and functions --------
    Node* head{};
    size_t numberOfElements{};
    void init() { head = new Node(); head->next = head; head->previous = head; numberOfElements = 0; }

public:
    struct iterator;    // Forward declaration

    // Constructor --------------------
    List() { init(); }
    explicit List(const size_t count) { init(); insert(begin(), count); }
    explicit List(const size_t count, const T& value) { init(); insert(begin(), count, value); };
    template <typename Iter>
    List(const Iter& first, const Iter& last) { init(); insert(begin(), first, last); }
    List(const List& other) { init(), insert(begin(), other.begin(), other.end()); };

    List(List&& other) : head(other.head), numberOfElements(other.numberOfElements) { other.init(); }
    List(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { init(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); }
    template <int N> List(T(&other)[N]) { init(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); }
    template <int N> List(const T(&other)[N]) { init(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); }


    // Assignment ---------------------
    List& operator =(const List& other) { clear(); insert(begin(), other.begin(), other.end()); return *this; }
    List& operator =(List&& other) { clear(); head = other.head; numberOfElements = other.numberOfElements; other.init(); return *this; }
    List& operator =(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); return *this; }
    template <int N> List& operator =(const T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    template <int N> List& operator =(T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }

    template <typename Iter> void assign(const Iter& first, const Iter& last) { clear(); insert(begin(), first, last); }
    template <int N> void assign(const T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    template <int N> void assign(T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    void assign(const size_t count, const T& value) { clear(); insert(begin(), count, value); }
    void assign(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); }

    // Destructor ---------------------
    ~List() { clear(); }

    // Element Access -----------------
    T& front() { return *begin(); }
    T& back() { return *(--end()); }

    // Iterators ----------------------
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(head->next, head); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(head, head); }

    // Capacity -----------------------
    size_t size() const { return numberOfElements; }
    bool empty() { return size() == 0; }

    // Modifiers ----------------------
    void clear();

    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const T& value);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition);
    template <class Iter, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator<Iter>::value, bool> = true>
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const Iter& first, const Iter& last);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const size_t& count, const T& value);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const std::initializer_list<T>& il);

    iterator erase(const iterator& posToDelete);
    iterator erase(const iterator& first, const iterator& last);

    void pop_front() { erase(begin()); };
    void push_front(const T& d) { insert(begin(), d); }

    void pop_back() { erase(--end()); };
    void push_back(const T& d) { insert(end(), d); }

    void resize(size_t count, const T& value);
    void resize(size_t count);

    void swap(List& other) { std::swap(head, other.head); std::swap(numberOfElements, other.numberOfElements); }

    // Operations --------------------
    void reverse();

    // Non standard inefficient functions --------------------------
    T& operator[](const size_t index) const { return begin()[index]; }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Define iterator capability ---------------------------------------------
    struct iterator {

        // Definitions ----------------
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;

        // Data -----------------------
        Node* iter{};
        Node* head{};

        // Constructor ----------------
        iterator(Node* const node, Node* const h) : iter(node), head(h) {};
        iterator() {};

        // Dereferencing --------------
        reference operator*() const { return iter->data; }
        reference operator->() const { return &**this; }

        // Arithmetic operations ------
        iterator operator++() { iter = iter->next; return *this; }
        iterator operator--() { iter = iter->previous; return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) { iterator tmp = *this; ++* this; return tmp; }
        iterator operator--(int) { iterator tmp = *this; --* this; return tmp; }

        iterator operator +(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++temp; else while (k++)--temp; return temp;
        }
        iterator operator +=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++* this; else while (k++)--* this; return *this;
        };
        iterator operator -(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--temp; else while (k++)++temp; return temp;
        }
        iterator operator -=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--* this; else while (k++)++* this; return *this;
        };
        // Comparison ----------------- (typical space ship implementation)
        bool operator ==(const iterator& other) const { return iter == other.iter; };
        bool operator !=(const iterator& other) const { return iter != other.iter; };
        bool operator < (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter < 0; };
        bool operator <= (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter <= 0; };
        bool operator > (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter > 0; };
        bool operator >= (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter >= 0; };

        // Special non standard functions -----------------
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& other) const;
        reference operator[] (const size_t index);
    };
};


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Implementation of list functions. This would normally go into a TCC file -----------------------

// List class functions ---------------
template <typename T>
void List<T>::clear() {

    for (Node* nextNode{}, * currentNode(head->next); currentNode != head; currentNode = nextNode) {
        nextNode = currentNode->next;
        delete currentNode;
    }
    init();
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const T& value)
{
    Node* nodeInsertBeforePosition = insertBeforePosition.iter;
    Node* newNode = new Node(nodeInsertBeforePosition, nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous, value);
    nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous = newNode;
    (newNode->previous)->next = newNode;
    ++numberOfElements;
    return iterator(newNode, head);
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition)
{
    Node* nodeInsertBeforePosition = insertBeforePosition.iter;
    Node* newNode = new Node(nodeInsertBeforePosition, nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous);
    nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous = newNode;
    (newNode->previous)->next = newNode;
    ++numberOfElements;
    return iterator(newNode, head);
}

template <typename T>
template <class Iter, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator<Iter>::value, bool>>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const Iter& first, const Iter& last) {
    iterator result(insertBeforePosition.iter, head);
    if (first != last) {
        result = insert(insertBeforePosition, *first);
        Iter i(first);
        for (++i; i != last; ++i)
            insert(insertBeforePosition, *i);
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const size_t& count, const T& value) {

    iterator result(insertBeforePosition.iter, head);
    if (count != 0u) {
        result = insert(insertBeforePosition, value);
        for (size_t i{ 1u }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(insertBeforePosition, value);
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const std::initializer_list<T>& il) {
    return insert(insertBeforePosition, il.begin(), il.end());
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::erase(const List<T>::iterator& posToDelete) {

    iterator result = posToDelete;
    ++result;

    Node* nodeToDelete = posToDelete.iter;

    if (nodeToDelete != head) {

        nodeToDelete->previous->next = nodeToDelete->next;
        nodeToDelete->next->previous = nodeToDelete->previous;

        delete nodeToDelete;
        --numberOfElements;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::erase(const List<T>::iterator& first, const List<T>::iterator& last) {
    iterator result{ end() };
    if (first == begin() && last == end())
        clear();
    else {
        while (first != last)
            first = erase(first);
        result = last;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::resize(size_t count) {
    if (numberOfElements < count)
        for (size_t i{ numberOfElements }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(end());
    else
        while (count--)
            pop_back();
}
template <typename T>
void List<T>::resize(size_t count, const T& value) {
    if (numberOfElements < count)
        for (size_t i{ numberOfElements }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(end(), value);
    else
        while (count--)
            pop_back();
}
template <typename T>
void List<T>::reverse() {
    const Node* oldHead = head;

    for (Node* nptr = head; ; nptr = nptr->previous) {
        std::swap(nptr->next, nptr->previous);
        if (nptr->previous == oldHead) // Previous was the original next
            break;
    }
}

// ------------------------------------
// Iterator functions -----------------
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator::difference_type List<T>::iterator::operator-(const iterator& other) const {

    difference_type result{};
    Node* nptr = head;

    int indexThis{ -1 }, indexOther{ -1 }, index{};

    do {
        nptr = nptr->next;
        if (nptr == iter)
            indexThis = index;
        if (nptr == other.iter)
            indexOther = index;
        ++index;
    } while (nptr != head);

    if (indexThis >= 0 and indexOther >= 0)
        result = indexThis - indexOther;
    return result;
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator::reference List<T>::iterator::operator[] (const size_t index) {
    Node* nptr = head->next;
    for (size_t i{}; i < index and nptr != head; ++i, nptr = nptr->next)
        ;
    return nptr->data;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This would be in a cpp file --------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {


    List<int> list3{ 10,20 };
    List<int>::iterator l3 = list3.end();
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k) {
        std::cout << *l3 << ' ';
        --l3;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Custom list
    List<int> list2{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for (int i : list2)
        std::cout << i << ' '; std::cout << '\n';

    // Delta works
    std::cout << list2.begin() - list2.end() << '\n';
    std::cout << list2.end() - list2.begin() << '\n';

    // Hopp Count works
    List<int>::iterator i = list2.end();
    while (i-- != list2.begin())
        std::cout << *i << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, I will try to understand the code first, and probably will use something similar in my case, as it seems much more stable and safe.